# Open a new window in a floating container i3

Tags: i3

I would like to open a new program in an already existing floating container in stacking mode.

More specifically, my use case is the following :
I use the scratchpad of i3 to always have terminal at my disposal. Most of the time, I create a stack of terminal in a regular windows, select all the stack and move it to my scratchpad. I can then access the scratchpad and move between the different windows in it. I would like to be able to open additional terminals in my scratchpad when it is in focus in front of me but opening a terminal with `mod + Enter`opens in in the background workspace.

I don't mind having a different shortcut to perform this action.

Any thoughts on how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup for use with xpad (it's like sticky notes) that I always want to open as a floating window. I use this:

```
for_window [class="xpad"] floating enable
```

You can get the class name to use with `xwininfo`

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to move the floating container to a new workplace, unfloat it, move the new window to that workplace, select everything in that workplace, float it again, and move back to the original workplace. It is tedious, but could probably be automated. One disadvantage is that you lose the original geometry of the float.